# Generate Swift Code From Changed GraphQL File Without Pushing Changes To The Cloud

Tags: swift, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I use AWS Amplify & GraphQL inside my iOS project. I would like to update my API.swift file based on my changed GraphQL file. The following Amplify CLI command accomplishes this, but pushes changes to the cloud...

```
amplify push
```

How can I generate an updated GraphQL file without pushing changes to the cloud?

Comment: I believe it's `amplify codegen`

Comment: I tried amplify codegen --no-download to generate the new API.swift file based on my changed local .graphql file. However, it doesn't work. The regular amplify codegen generates the API.swift file from remote .graphql file...

Answer (score 0):

Are you making changes to your schema or your queries/mutations? If you're making changes to your queries and mutations inside your graphql folder with the queries.graphql, mutations.graphql, and subscriptions.graphql, you can run `amplify codegen types`